# Error 95 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my vb.net solution, why do I get the error in the title??

```
  Dim ids As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of [String])(comma_seperatedstring.Split(","c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is split the comma separated string into the IDs and store them in a generic list of type string - if that's the case, I'm not aware of a way you can initialize the list like that.

Someting like this should work:

```
Dim ids As New List(Of String)()

Dim individualIds As String() = comma_separatedstring.Split(",")

For Each id As String in individualIds

    ids.Add(id)
Next
```

The syntax may be a bit off (I don't do VB.NET very often), but the basic idea is to split the comma seaprated string into an array, then loop through the array and adding each element to the generic list.

There is `From` keyword in 4.0 that allows you to initialize the list with the following syntax:

```
Dim ids As New List(Of String) From { "a", "b", "c" }
```

But it appears you have to explicitly list the elements (in other words, you couldn't do `From { comma_separatedstring.Split(",") }`.

See [Collection Initializers Overview (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For the similar problem I was having, getting "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Split' can be called without a narrowing conversion" on this line of code:

```
Dim sStrings() As String = sArg.Split("=", 2)
```

".paul. _" responded with the answer that solved it here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd3c446f-46b2-4a60-9d10-6d31f30b6e7d/what-has-changed-in-split-from-previous-to-current-versions-of-net-or-vb

The new working code is:

```
Dim sStrings() As String = sArg.Split(New Char() {"="c}, 2)
```